# Was Stilgar related to Chani on the paternal or maternal side?

Tags: dune

In the original three Dune novels, it is mentioned numerous times that Stilgar - Naib of Sietch Tabr and Paul's Fremen mentor/friend - is uncle to Chani, Paul's wife. However, Chani is the daughter of Liet Kynes, the Imperial planetologist from the first novel. So... that means that Stilgar is either A) the brother of Kynes, or B) the brother of Chani's mother. But which one? I'm guessing it's the latter, since him being Liet's brother should have been a plot point in the first novel.

**Was Stilgar related to Chani on the paternal or maternal side?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stilgar is Chani's Great Uncle on her **Paternal** side, according to the "Prelude to Dune" series by Brian Herbert and Kevin J. Anderson. Stilgar's sister Frieth married Pardot Kynes and bore Chani's father Liet Kynes.

*Exerpts from "House Atreides"*

Frieth is Stilgar's sister:

> Frieth, Stilgar's quiet sister, stayed by the young man's bedside, always busy, her blue-in-blue eyes darting from side to side in search of something else to do.

Chani's father Liet is the son of Frieth and Pardot Kynes:

> Others knew about his place in Plaster Basin, of course, but he wanted to be the
>   first to show it to Frieth and their baby son Liet. "I'm taking you to see
>   something incredible," Kynes said as his wife dismantled the minicamp.

Comment: Can you provide a quote to confirm this?

Comment: since there is no single quote to sum up the lineage, I will use several from "House Atreides."

1)Stilgar's unwed sister Frieth was offered to him as a wife. Almost without the Planetologist noticing, she seemed to have adopted him...

2) "And there is more news, Umma Kynes," the man said. "I've been instructed to tell you that your wife Frieth has given birth to a strong young son who is sure to be the pride of his sietch one day." 

3)When his son Liet was a year and a half old, Pardot...

Comment: Great, now add this into your answer :-)

Comment: Excellent - exactly what I was looking for. Answer accepted! Now I'm curious as to how old Stilgar was... but that's a different question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is definitively stated, but I did find [one analysis on the web](http://www.leighkimmel.com/reading/essays/stilgarsancestry.shtml) that suggests that it would be maternal side, but not blood. It suggests that Stilgar is a brother in law to Liet, rather than blood brother.